# PS-4 PHP package - Main folder classes are not able to access the sub folder classes - Namespace

Tags: php, namespaces, composer-php, psr-4

I am learning to setup PHP package with PSR-4 autoload using composer. I have managed to set up the working package. But I can access the classes in the same directory but cannot access the sub folder classes from main folder class.

adding my src code link here https://github.com/nsatheesh87/PSR-4-PHP-Test

Kernel.php  from src directory trying to access the Http->Request.php class but only i can get Class cannot found error. Also I Checked the namespaces

Comment: I don't see why your namespace error. But, you have another problem in __construct function of Kernel, an object Request is required a parameter and in your src/app.php you init with no params, this can't work. You should pass a new Request object at initialisation of Kernel

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You miss parameter with create Kernel object
https://github.com/nsatheesh87/PSR-4-PHP-Test/blob/master/src/app.php#L14

This constructor require object of Request class
https://github.com/nsatheesh87/PSR-4-PHP-Test/blob/master/src/Kernel.php#L11

Comment: Thanks @buildok. Time for me to learn more about OOPS implementation